# How to assign objects read from csv file with pandas to some Class?

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have one class for example:

```py
class Automobile:
  def __init__(self, name, lastname, country, year, model, price):
```

and I want to read csv file which looks like table with columns the same as the attributes of class Automobile. I want to create a list of objects of Automobile class from that csv file. Could anyone help?

Comment: Then unpack the columns into attributes. You cannot magically turn tabular data into attributes without doing some parsing/transformation. Nor would you really want that

Comment: @roganjosh However, `csv.DictReader` and `**` will get them more than half-way there

Comment: If you read in an CSV and call it `self.data` then you have a nice, self-contained, namespace where you can access columns as though it was (effectively) a dictionary. It's a few extra keystrokes but it makes a whole lot more sense than an object that gets arbitrary attributes based on what you read in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV file has a header row with the headers matching the parameters' names, you can get this functionality for basically free with `**` and `csv.DictReader`.

test.csv

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

```py
import csv

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

a_objects = []

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        a_objects.append(A(**line))
```

If the CSV file does not have explicit headers then it is possible to pass them ad-hoc to `DictReader`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['a', 'b'])
```

Keep in mind this is will fail as soon as either the code or the CSV file changes so you will need some error handling (or at least protect the class's `__init__` against unknown columns with `**kwrags`).

Comment: This is row-wise. My impression of the question was column-wise?

Comment: @roganjosh Don't know, however *"columns the same as the attributes of class"* sounds row-wise?

Comment: Looking back over the question, I don't know any more. We've both interpreted it in completely different ways

Comment: It seems that this should work. It's just that I don't have header (column names). And the column order is the same as parameters in class. Is there a way to define column names first and than to use this method?

Comment: You could use a plain `csv.reader` (not the DictReader) and then create your objects as `A(*line)`. Note: positional args not keyword args, so one asterisk not two.

Comment: @mungos032 I added a small workaround in case the CSV file does not contain headers

Comment: @DeepSpace Great! Solved it with your workaround! Thanks a lot man!